# Surveys in other languages than English

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, soft-question, big-picture

Where can I find surveys in languages than English ?

If the question is found to be interesting (it could be usefull for graduated students who are not fluent in English for instance), it would be practical to propose one reference by answer, i.e. by subject and by language.

Comment: Shouldn't you narrow down the scope of those surveys to avoid an exceedingly long list that will not necessarily be helpful?

Comment: It would be necessary if the list grows too much, which is not the case at all...I posted the question when I saw the very interesting survey in French by C. Bazgan. Then I wondered whether others surveys (in other languages) could be interesting as well.

Answer (score 1):

To open the list, here is a survey on SAT in French by Cristina Bazgan: 
[Optimisation Combinatoire : problèmes paradigmatiques et nouvelles problématiques, Hermes, ed. Vangelis Paschos, pp. 21-50, 2007](http://www.lamsade.dauphine.fr/~bazgan/Papers/chap07.pdf)

Comment: I would love it if you translated for us! :)